# Qual é a função do typedef no struct em C? Posso usar o struct sem ele?

Tags: c, struct, estrutura-de-dados

Estou estudando estrutura de dados em C, e toda vez minha professora usa o `typedef` nos `struct`, mas não entendo a função dele.

Comment: Poderia colocar o exemplo de `struct` na pergunta?

Comment: para criar uma matriz adjacente usando grafo, ex: typedef struct{ int matriz[MAX][MAX] int numeroDeVertices};

Comment: @RennanReis A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 7):

Não é só para `struct`. O `typedef` é usado para definir um tipo de dados, como o nome já indica.

Além dos tipos já existentes na linguagem você pode criar os seus e funcionarem como qualquer outro.

Um tipo definido pode ser algo muitos simples, como apenas um nome diferente (uma abstração) para um tipo existente, como pode ser a composição de alguns valores em um determinado formato que criam uma forma de valor diferente do que existe.

Você pode fazer isto com a `struct`, mas se fizer apenas com ela não cria um tipo novo para a linguagem usar com um nome disponível sempre que o carregar. Ainda criará um tipo novo, mas ele será considerado anônimo para a linguagem, ele terá um nome apenas para o comando `struct`, o que é chato de usar e pode causar alguns equívocos. Com o `typedef` fica tudo mais fácil porque ele deixa simples, limpo e correto. Basicamente ele é uma abstração.

Costuma-se recomendar o uso do maiúsculo na inicial do nome para evitar conflitar com outros símbolos, ou usar um sufixo `_t`. Algo assim:

```
typedef struct { int x; int y; } Ponto;
```

Aí você usa na declaração de uma variável:

```
Ponto ponto;
```

Ou *cast*:

```
(Ponto)ponto
```

Sem ele:

```
struct ponto ponto;
```

Ou:

```
(struct ponto)ponto
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Typing/Typedef.c).

Quando usa um nome com `struct` o padrão de nome é menos importante porque ele certamente é um tipo, ele não pode ser usado, e portanto confundido, com outros identificadores do código. Quando usa um `typedef` a `struct` não precisa ter nome. Pode ter uma `struct` anônima sem `typedef`, mas aí ela não poderá ser usada em lugar algum mais na aplicação.

Comment: O "mas aí ela não poderá ser usada em lugar algum mais na aplicação." quer dizer que se eu criar um typedef em um arquivo de cabeçalho e não definir o nome para a struct, eu não posso chamar esse tipo em qualquer arquivo .c que esteja incluindo este arquivo de cabeçalho?

Comment: Não é isso, pegue a frase toda: `Pode ter uma struct anônima **sem typedef**, mas aí ela não poderá ser usada em lugar algum mais na aplicação.`

Comment: Ahhhhhhhh, agora entendi, eu estava lendo errado, obrigado

Answer (score -2):

Veja bem, o *typedef* não precisa ser usado necessariamente com *structs*.

Uma *struct* define um novo tipo de dados, um registro que pode conter informações de vários tipos de dados ao mesmo tempo, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
struct pessoa {
     char nome[50];
     int idade;
     float altura;
};
```

Para criar uma variável do tipo **pessoa** na *main*, poderíamos fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
int main() {
    struct pessoa p;
}
```

Veja que teríamos que carregar a palavra reservada *struct* toda vez que nos referíssemos a alguma variável com o tipo definido. É aí que entra o *typedef*, que ao pé da letra seria uma "definição de tipo".

Basicamente, sua função é criar um "apelido" para tipos de dados, permitindo que não seja necessário escrever aquele tipo de dados toda vez que for chamar uma variável desse tipo, e isso é válido para *structs* também. Vejamos o exemplo anterior, imagine que queremos nos referir a *struct pessoa* apenas como **Pessoa**:

```
typedef struct pessoa {
     char nome[50];
     int idade;
     float altura;
} Pessoa;
```

O trecho de código acima basicamente diz que queremos chamar a *struct pessoa* de **Pessoa**. Agora, para declarar uma variável do tipo *struct pessoa*, podemos fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
int main() {
     Pessoa p;
}
```

Resumindo, o *typedef* permite associar um nome a um tipo de dados, podendo deixar seu código mais legível e enxuto.