# Precisa alocar memória quando tem struct dentro de outra struct?

Tags: c, struct, memória, malloc

Quero guardar e recuperar dados de uma `struct`, mas essa `struct` possui outras struct dentro dela, não sei se eu fiz correto, não sei se devo utilizar `typedef` ou só `struct`.

N ão sei se devo usar um `malloc()` para cada sub `struct`, ou o primeiro já calcula todo o espaço requerido.

```
Mesas = malloc(sizeof(stTable));
ou 
Mesas->PlayersList[0] = malloc(9*sizeof(stPlayer));
...
```

Também preciso que `struct stTable *Mesas;` seja um *array* com 100 posições.
para usar tipo:

```
Mesas[99]->Flop->Card01 = 10;
Mesas[1]->Flop->Card01 = 2;
ou (qual a diferença)
Mesas[99].Flop.Card01 = 10;
Mesas[1].Flop.Card01 = 2;

typedef struct stCard {
    BYTE carta;
    BYTE pinta;
}stCard;


typedef struct stHand {
    stCard* Card01;
    stCard* Card02;
}stHand;

typedef struct stFlop {
    stCard* Card01;
    stCard* Card02;
    stCard* Card03;
}stFlop;

typedef struct stTurn {
    stCard* Card01;
}stTurn;

typedef struct stRiver {
    stCard* Card01;
}stRiver;

typedef struct stPlayer {
    DWORD Id;
    char Nome[250];
    DWORD BaseAddr;
    DWORD Fichas;
    DWORD Bet;
    DWORD LastBet;
    stHand* Mao;

}stPlayer;

typedef struct stTable {
    BYTE        Id;
    DWORD       BaseAddr;
    DWORD       LastHand;
    DWORD       CurrentHand;
    DWORD       Ante;
    DWORD       SmallBlind;
    DWORD       BigBlind;
    stPlayer*   PlayersList[9];
    stFlop*     Flop;
    stTurn*     Turn;
    stRiver*    River;
}stTable;

struct stTable *Mesas;


void init_t() 
{
    Mesas = malloc(sizeof(stTable));

    Mesas->Id = 100;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A questão não é essa. Acho perigoso fazer um código tão complexo sem entender o que está fazendo, eu reveria isto.

Não sei nem se precisa de um `malloc()` aí. Pode ser, apenas estou dizendo que a pergunta não deixa claro o que deseja. Do jeito que está até precisa, mas talvez não deveria. Mas a pergunta diz que quer ter um *array* com 100 posições, se quer um *array*, porque não criar um no lugar do `malloc()`. Se não consegue decidir sobre isso realmente está fazendo algo bem mais complexo do que consegue nesse momento. Mas se vai insistir no `malloc()` então reserve o espaço para 100 elementos deste tipo e não apenas 1 como fez. Algo assim:

```
Mesas = malloc(sizeof(stTable) * 100);
```

Um conceito errado é que tem `structs` dentro de uma `struct`, e não tem, se tivesse haveria a declaração dela ali dentro. Você tem vários membros dentro de uma `struct`, não importa o que são estes dados, não deveria ter saber o que eles são e todos os dados declarados ali tem seu espaço reservado ali.

Acontece que alguns desses membros são ponteiros, imagino que percebe isto. Não sei se sabe que um ponteiro é um dado de tamanho fixo (4 bytes em arquiteturas 32 bits ou 8 bytes em 64 bits) e que terá esse espaço reservado dentro da `struct`. O que parece que não sabe é que esse ponteiro estará apontando para um objeto em algum lugar. Esse lugar provavelmente é um espaço no [*heap*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101), afinal a `struct` já está alocada no *heap*, então seria complicado, embora não impossível, que eles estivem em outro lugar, afinal a chance do tempo de vida deles fora do *heap* serem menores que o [tempo de vida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101) da `struct` é grande.

Então é quase certo que para cada ponteiro desses você terá que dar um `malloc()` com o tamanho do tipo do objeto que ele aponta, por exemplo:

```
Mesas->Flop = malloc(sizeofFlop);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Allocation/StructInStruct.c).

Só depois poderia colocar valores nesse objeto.

Cuidado porque você terá que liberar todos esses dados assim que eles não forem mais necessários e não pode fazer antes do momento adequado porque poderia acessar um local que já foi liberado mas ainda está em uso, antão pode ter um vazamento de memória ou *dangling pointer*. Isto não é simples de fazer ainda mais sem dominar completamente esses conceitos todos. A sua pergunta é a parte fácil, gerenciar a memória é bem mais complicado que isso.

Não está errado, mas achei a nomenclatura adota ruim. E acho que a modelagem também não está muito adequada. Provavelmente nem precisa de todas essas `structs`. E tenho a impressão que talvez não precisaria ter tantos ponteiros quanto colocou. Mas novamente não posso afirmar nada sem conhecer o problema em profundidade. Pelo menos para fazer algo sem tanto conhecimento eu faria da forma mais simples possível.

Leia sobre o `typedef` em [Qual a maneira correta de declarar uma struct em C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/162173/101) e [Qual é a função do typedef no struct em C? Posso usar o struct sem ele?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/364771/101). O uso aí está bastante inconsistente.

Comment: eu estou acostumado a programar em java POO, agora estou com um trabalho para fazer em C e estou com dificuldade em entender isso, pois bem, deixa eu tentar te explicar melhor o que estou tentando fazer.

Comment: em java se cria uma classe Table, dentro dessa classe posso colocar minhas variaveis, gets, sets, inclusive essas variaveis podem ser outra classe, é dai que vem essa minha ideia de criar um struct dentro de outro struct, eu entendo o conceito de ponteiro, acho que eu nao preciso desses ponteiros, vou reformular o codigo e editar a pergunta, se possível leia novamente e tente me ajudar.

eu so quero salvar meus dados dentro de uma struct tipo:(sets)
table[0].PlayersList[2].Nome = "Joao";
table[1].PlayerList[3].Nome = "Maria";
e recuperar valores (gets)
table[0].PlayerList[2].Nome;

Comment: devo declarar a estrutura typedef struct stPlayer e usar stPlayer
ou declarar  a estrutura   struct stPlayer e usar  struct stPlayer

Comment: Mesmo em Java tem essa modelagem estaria errada, mas em C mais errada ainda, não pode tentar fazer Java em C. E nem vou falar que Java já induz as pessoas fazerem muita coisa errada e a mais errada de todas é fazer coisas sem nem entender porque estão fazendo aquilo. Você não pode reformular a pergunta, eu respondi o que foi perguntado, mudar a pergunta invalida a minha resposta. Você fez uma pergunta e eu respondi. Se tem outra dúvida tem que fazer outra pergunta, está está respondida. Se não resolve o problema por completo é só porque a pergunta não está completa, eu só posso respondê-la.

Comment: ja marquei como correta, voce pode ler novamente e me ajudar:

Comment: se você estiver fazendo esse projeto pra aprender, va em frente. Se for um programa para usar, melhor usar uma linguagem de mais alto-nível do que C - pode ser Java. Você tem que cuidar de muito mais detalhes - e todos críticos, do que com uma linguagem que já possa pelo menos criar e descriar objetos sozinha.

Comment: @VictorCosta como eu disse, essa questão está respondida, se tem outras faça nova pergunta com o seu problema  agora, sobre o uso do `malloc()`. Vou repetir, esse problema está mal definido até para Java, não parece que deveria ser assim, em C faz menos sentido ainda. Parece que deveria ter no máximo 3 `structs` (em Java seriam 3 classes) e não deveria alocar nada a não ser a mesa, e olhe lá (lembrando que estou especulando). Quando modela errado toda a aplicação está condenada a cometer um erro atrás do outro. E não é assim que aprende C, não é pulando etapas porque "sabe" Java.

Comment: Já consegui resolver, obrigado, e sim eu preciso alocar memoria, pois estou trabalhando com hook em outra aplicação, usei calloc, que já aloca a quantidade que preciso para o array, e realmente nao precisava de mais ponteiros, somente o da mesa.